# how to set cron job with http-post on google-app-engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, cron

I have set a google-cloud cron job like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cronentries>
    <cron>
        <url>/match</url>
        <description>bla bla</description>
        <schedule>every 2 minutes</schedule>
    </cron>
</cronentries>
```

but i see in the google cloud console it sends a "get"

how can i change it to "post" ?

Comment: if you explain the goal for which you need a POST you may get suggestions for achieving that goal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. From  [Scheduling Tasks With Cron for Java](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron) (emphasis mine):

> A cron job invokes a URL, using an **HTTP GET request**, at a given
>   time of day. An cron job request is subject to the same limits as
>   those for [push task queues](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Task_Queue).

If you really, really need a POST you can trigger one from inside your cron job itself.